# Has_one through AND has_many through together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i have 3 models:

- Sale
- Customer
- Customer Address

-Each SALE should have only one CUSTOMER

-Each CUSTOMER can have more than one SALE

That works great, there's no problem here, but now i need something like this:

-Each SALE should have only one CUSTOMER_ADDRESS

-Each CUSTOMER can have more than one CUSTOMER_ADDRESS

---

And then, how can i do this?

Can i use has_one through and has_many through together?

Comment: Between which models you want that association? I don't see such need here..

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a 1-n association between Customer and Address:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Then add the order model and setup the associations:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :sales
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :sales_as_shipping_address, class_name: 'Sale',
                                       foreign_key: 'shipping_address_id'
end

class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address'
end
```

This creates two seperate associations - both Sale and Customer have distinct associations to Address.

If you want to join Customer to Address via sale we can do:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :sales
  has_many :shipping_addresses, through: :sales, 
                               source: :shipping_address
end
```

Comment: I need to create "shipping_address_id" in Address table?

Comment: No - `shipping_address_id` goes on the `sales` table. `belongs_to` places the foreign key on the models table. Putting it on `addresses` would mean that a adress could on be used in one sale.